# Ubuntu - utilities ask about each file?

Tags: ubuntu, tar, rm

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 after doing something like sudo rm *.log it asks me about each file.

do you want to delete 1234.log y/n ?
do you want to delete 12345.log y/n ?

It is having this same behavior with tar

add file 1234.log to folder.tar ? y/n

If i press enter it skips the file. Is there a way to disable this ? I don't remember this being the default behavior.

Comment: Man pages should really be your first stop before asking questions like this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no evidence that the user researched the question on their own before coming here.

Comment: i googled it but im not sure what to ask

Comment: You ssh into your system, type `man rm` and then start reading.

Comment: the problem was the shell, not rm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are tripping over a feature. Check your shell environment and aliases to see if -i is being added to your commands and note that for at least rm Ubuntu may well have shipped it this way on purpose.

Here is the information for the safe-rm [package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/safe-rm) in 12.10 (QQ) release.

Answer (score 0):

From the `rm` man page:

```
-f, --force
              ignore nonexistent files, never prompt
```

With regards to `tar`, it sounds as if you're using the `-w` flag, which asks for confirmation for each file. Are you using that flag? If not, perhaps there is a shell alias set up for `tar` which uses that flag by default.